# nodejs - Call a function inside a parent module from a child module

Tags: javascript, node.js

Let's say I have a file called `parent.js` with the following source code:

```
var child = require('./child')

var parent = {
    f: function() {
        console.log('This is f() in parent.');
    }
};

module.exports = parent;

child.target();
```

and a file called `child.js` with the following source code:

```
var child = {
    target: function() {
        // The problem is here..
    }
}

module.exports = child;
```

and I execute the file using the following command:

```
node parent.js
```

The thing is, I want to execute `f()` inside `child.js` directly without using any `require(...)` statement. Previously, I'm trying to execute this statement inside `target()` in `child.js`:

```
module.parent.f()
```

and

```
module.parent.exports.f()
```

but it doesn't work. The strange thing is, when I execute `console.log(module.parent.exports)` inside `child.js`, the following output appear:

```
{ f: [Function] }
```

So why can't I call `f()` directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative to what Lee Jenkins suggested, you could change your code to this (hard to explain without just showing code)

parent.js

```
var parent = {
    f: function() {
        console.log('This is f() in parent.');
    }
};

var child = require('./child')(parent);

module.exports = parent;

child.target();
```

child.js

```
module.exports = function (parent) {
    return child = {
        target: function() {
            parent.f();
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using a callback function:

```
var child = {
    target: function( callback ) {
        callback();
    }
}

module.exports = child;
```

Then in parent.js call the target like this:

```
child.target( parent.f );
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try the following setup, using [**require.main**](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_main) **(module.parent is deprecated)** to access the parent functions.

**parent.js**

```
var parent = {} 

parent.f = function(){
      console.log('called parent function from child');
    }

module.exports = {
  parent:parent
}

var child = require('./child.js');
```

**child.js**

```
var child = {};
var parent = require.main.exports.parent;

child.f = function(){
  parent.f();
}

//call parent function here
child.f();

module.exports = {
  child:child
}
```